# Getting only Numeric values as input in python - providing response for string values

Tags: python, for-loop, oop, while-loop, integer

Below is my code. I am trying to loop this while code input, so if someone gives anything other than a numeric then it has to respond with the below message and then ask for the number again. But i am stuck it tried many variations of whiel try blocks.. but the output seem to be if the number is valid, then it gives the response[ prime or not] along with the secondary print value about the non numeric and if the input is non numeric, it gives an error for it being non numeric.... any help or suggestions pls

```
def prime_checker(number) :
    is_prime = True
    for i in range(2, number) :
        if number % i == 0 :
            is_prime = False
    if is_prime :
        print("It's a prime number")
    else :
        print("Its not a prime number")

should_continue = True
num = int(input("Check this number: "))
prime_checker(number=num)
while not num == int():
    result = input("You have entered a non numeric value, please enter a number to continue else enter 'no' to exit. '.\n")
    if result == "no":
        should_continue = False
        print("Goodbye")
```

Comment: Here is the response: Check this number: 40
Its not a prime number
You have entered a non numeric value, please enter a number to continue else enter 'no' to exit. '.

Answer (score 0):

You should check for the type of the variable and not the variable itself:

```
  ...
  while not isinstance(num, int):
  ....
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have `while not num == int()` You can have while `num.isdigit() == False`. Remember when you are using input you are receiving a string. And you need a `try: except:` block to handle the `int(num)` check or use `num.isdigit()`. You are not using your `should_continue` variable anywhere meaningful. You need to use a `break` command to exit the `while loop`.

*Changed your code to make it more sensible*

Comment: When i run the code, i get the following error please. :   num = int(input("Check this number: "))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'yes